# Fastest Way To Export XLSX to CSV

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I just tried using the XSSF XLSX2CSV sample using the SAX Event API to export a 630k row by 5 column spreadsheet to CSV using OpenCSV to write it.
It takes a minimum of 70 seconds (although I originally saw 20 minutes when profiling the web server) to complete the operation whereas Excel does it in less than 10 seconds.

Part of the issue is that the org.apache.poi.xssf.eventusermodel.XSSFSheetXMLHandler.SheetContentsHandler interface looks like this:

```
 /**
  * You need to implement this to handle the results
  *  of the sheet parsing.
  */
 public interface SheetContentsHandler {
    /** A row with the (zero based) row number has started */
    public void startRow(int rowNum);
    /** A row with the (zero based) row number has ended */
    public void endRow(int rowNum);
    /**
     * A cell, with the given formatted value (may be null),
     *  and possibly a comment (may be null), was encountered */
    public void cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue, XSSFComment comment);
    /** A header or footer has been encountered */
    public void headerFooter(String text, boolean isHeader, String tagName);
 }
```

Note how you only have a Cell at a time and not a whole row.
My solution to this was to put the cells into a map using the column header as a key the use the endRow to write the row.

```
@Override
public void endRow(int rowNum) {
    if(currentRow == HEADER_ROW) {
        processRow(currentRow, columnHeaders);
    } else {
        processRow(currentRow, currentRowMap);
    }
}

private void processRow(int currentRow, LinkedHashMap<String, String> map) {
    String[] nextLine = map.values().toArray(new String[map.size()]);
    csvWriter.writeNext(nextLine);
}

/**
 * POI will not invoke this method if the cell is blank or if it detects there's no more data in the row.
 * Therefore, this is not necessarily invoked the same number of times each row.
 * The startRow method has initialised the currentRowMap to work around this.
 */
@Override
public void cell(String cellReference, String formattedValue, XSSFComment comment) {
    if(currentRow == HEADER_ROW) {
        columnHeaders.put(getColumnReference(cellReference), formattedValue);
    } else {
        String columnHeader = columnHeaders.get(getColumnReference(cellReference));
        currentRowMap.put(columnHeader, formattedValue);
    }
}

/**
 * Returns the alphabetic column reference from this cell reference. Example: Given 'A12' returns
 * 'A' or given 'BA205' returns 'BA'
 */
private static String getColumnReference(String cellReference) {

    if (StringUtils.isBlank(cellReference)) {
        return "";
    }

    return cellReference.split("[0-9]*$")[0];
}
```

Adding and reading to this map and getting the column reference for each cell is called 3M time and is very inefficient.

What are some faster options for exporting XLSX to CSV?

Comment: Clearly you're doing something wrong, but without seeing any code we cannot possibly help you.  Also, as your question is now worded (_"What are some faster options for exporting XLS and XLSX to CSV"_) it's off-topic as it's asking for an external resource recommendation.

Comment: The interface takes a cell because the file format stores one cell at a time! As for performance, it should only take a few seconds on a file like that. What heap size are you running with?

Comment: I just ran a micro benchmark and it took about 2 seconds to call the getColumnReference 3M times so I don't see how the whole file export can be done in a few seconds.

Answer (score -2):

Perl (Spreadsheet::ParseExcel) doesn't take that long.